# Unique combination in a table

Tags: database, django, postgresql

I have two tables: `House` and `Picture`. The `Picture` table has a column `homepage`, which is a `bool`, and a `house_id`. What this means is that houses have pictures, and only the pictures flagged as `homepage` will appear in the home page.

Problem: there should be only one home page picture per house. Or: there can be as many `(house_id, homepage):(1, False)` but only one `(house_id, homepage):(1, True)` tuples. How can I make that work for PostgreSQL?

Is there a name for a situation like that? That's not a Primary Key, of course, since there can be many `(1, False)` tuples.

The solution on the database helps. **Bonus points:** A solution on how to implement that on Django, on the model layer, would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can (and should) be solved on the DB level if you want to guarantee data integrity at all times. There are various ways, a [partial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) [`UNIQUE INDEX`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-unique.html) probably being the simplest and most effective.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX picture_homepage_uni ON picture (house_id) WHERE homepage;
```

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d1ace/1)

Will also speed up queries to retrieve the homepage pictures as collateral benefit.

#### Change schema

A different approach would be to add a column `homepage_id` to the table `house`, pointing to a selected picture. Automatically, only 1 picture can be selected. You wouldn't need `picture.homepage` any more. Referential integrity might be a bit tricky because of foreign key constraints in both directions, but I have working solutions like that.