# PostgreSQL Unique Constraint with Exclusions

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, unique-constraint, check-constraints

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo."TransportInteraction"
(
  "Id" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('dbo."TransportInteraction_Id_seq"'::regclass),
  "Message" character varying(256),
  "TransportActionId" integer NOT NULL,
  "TimeCreated" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  "TimeInserted" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  "TaskId" bigint
)
```

Generally, this table is mapping actions on a task. `TransportActionId` is an `integer` defining the type of action. Some action types must be unique per task and some others not.

So I need a constraint of type:
`UNIQUE ("TaskId", "TransportActionId")` applying to all actions with `TransportActionId != (2||3 || 4)`.

So all actions except those with `ActionId=2,3 or 4`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [**partial unique index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX transint_partial_uni_idx
ON dbo."TransportInteraction" ("TaskId", "TransportActionId")
WHERE TransportActionId NOT IN (2,3,4);
```

Related:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)
- [Unique combination in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040695/unique-combination-in-a-table/15042040#15042040)